# Custom Login Page for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to create a custom login page for my SP2010 site.

Now, I understand that I need to enable FBA (Form Based Authentication) for my application, but I couldn't do this. Because; new, extend and delete buttons are disabled in Web Application management page in Central Administration. Therefore, don't know why (I'm the admin and all), but I can't create a web application to enable forms authentication type.

I've done some reading on the net, but every page suggests a way that I can't follow because of the reasons above.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your user a member of farm administrators and a local administrator on all WFE in the farm? you need those permissions to create new web applications, because it creates new IIS websites.

Once the buttons becomes enabled, with sharepoint 2010 you will be creating a new web application that is "claims" based.

Comment: My username is shown in the list "Central Administration > Site Settings > People and Groups - Farm Administrators". Also I'm able to run the command "New-SPWebApplication" in SP2010 Management Shell without a permission error.